# Fredholm index and spectral flow

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Suppose $\alpha_s, s\in [0,1]$ is a smooth family of quadratic forms (regarded as symmetric matrices) on $\mathbb R^n$. Consider an operator:
$$
d_\alpha:= \frac{d}{ds} + \alpha_s: W^{1,2}(\mathbb R, \mathbb R^n) \to L^2(\mathbb R, \mathbb R^n)
$$
Denote by $\nu_s$ the negative eigenspace of the symmetric matrix $\alpha_s$. Then the reference I read suggests to extend $d_\alpha$ by adding the linear span of $e^{-s\lambda}v$ (with $\lambda$ negative eigenvalue of $\alpha_1$ and $v$ corresponding eigenvectors. That is, it gives an operator
$$
\tilde d_\alpha: W^{1,2}(\mathbb R, \mathbb R^n)\oplus \nu_{\alpha_1} \to L^2(\mathbb R, \mathbb R^n)
$$
My questions are about the following claims(without details in my book):

1. $\tilde d_\alpha$ is surjective
2. $\tilde d_\alpha$ has kernel, identified with $\nu_{\alpha_0}$
3. $\dim \nu_{\alpha_0} = \mathrm{index}(d_\alpha) + \dim \nu_{\alpha_1}$

Also, the way of the extending operator looks strange, do you know its motivation? Thanks